# Setting ScrolViewArea scroll values?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, scrollview

I'm trying to move a scrollbar position in a `ScrollViewArea` in the code-behind. This is what I'm currently doing:

```
try
{
    ScrollViewer v = GetTemplateChild( "ScrollArea" ) as ScrollViewer;
    v.SetValue( ScrollViewer.HorizontalOffsetProperty, 0 );
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
}
```

But I keep [getting an exception at v.SetValue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUZVJ.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `ScrollToHorizontalOffset` method.

```
v.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(0);
```